# Get the "exact" page of a \ref command in .log or .aux files

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, auxiliary-files

I need to write a script in `elisp` that warns me when a float appears before the page where that float is first referred.
From the `.aux` file I can extract the label, the number, and the page number of the float. But I need to get the exact page in where each `\ref` command is placed.
I tried:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
\let\oldref\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{{\oldref{#1}\typeout{RefsPagesInLog --> {#1} \thepage}}}
```

so e.g., `\ref{fig:2}` in the `.tex` files prints:

```
RefsPagesInLog --> {fig:2} 29
```

in the log file. It almost works but sometimes fails. In very few cases it prints a wrong page number in the log file so my script fails.

Is there a trick to achieve the same goal?

The data I need are the label `\ref` refers to, and the "exact" page where the refs appear.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. A working/compilable document would be really nice, not just fragments

Comment: You're right. Because I'm professional typesetter the documents on which I work are copyrighted. I'll need some time to prepare a simplified example. Thanks.

Comment: Just a comment to explain where the problem (probably) comes from: `\thepage` is not completely reliable in the document main text, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/239452/82917 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/338084/82917.

Comment: @campa Thanks! I already realized that the problem comes from the page and the examples you gave me really clarified me the reason. So I'd need to use `\label` to get the exact page number in the `.aux`. But I'm not able to imagine how to label a `\ref` command.

Comment: there's such a thing as a `\hyperanchor` that could be used (with a `\label`) to identify the location of a `\ref`.  but each one has to be unique, so you'd still have the problem of identifying the `\ref`s because you'd have to know the label name for each one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will write

```
\ref@page{<key>}{<page>}
```

in the `.aux` file for each `\ref{<key>}` command found in the document.

In the example case, you get

```
\ref@page{somefigure}{4}
```

which can be read by your external script.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{etoolbox}    
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\NR@setref}[1]{%
    \ref@page@write{#1}%
    \begingroup\@safe@activestrue\expandafter\endgroup
    \expandafter\NR@@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname
  }%
}
\newcommand{\ref@page@write}[1]{%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\ref@page{#1}{\thepage}}%
}
\newcommand{\ref@page}[2]{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\blindtext[10]

\clearpage

\ref{somefigure}

\section{First section}\label{firstsec}

\blindtext[50]


\begin{figure}
  \caption{Some figure}\label{somefigure}
\end{figure}

\blindtext[50]

\section{Second section}\label{secondsec}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works fine. I'll write an alternative version of my script using this hack then I'll test them for a while. Thank you!

Comment: Finally I adopted this solution because it works also with `\ref` commands within the `caption` environment.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This labels (!) the usage of `\ref` with the label `refusage:\therefusage` and extracts the page where this occurs with `\getpagerefnumber` (contained in `refcount` package, but loaded by `hyperref` anyway!)

- Remember to compile twice to get the cross-references correct!
- Do not manipulate the `refusage` counter!

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}    
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{refusage}

\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
\let\oldref\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{{\refstepcounter{refusage}\label{refusage:\therefusage}\oldref{#1}\typeout{RefsPagesInLog --> {#1} \getpagerefnumber{refusage:\therefusage}}}}
\robustify\ref
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[10]

\clearpage

\ref{somefigure}

\section{First section}\label{firstsec}

\blindtext[50]


\begin{figure}
  \caption{Some figure}\label{somefigure}
\end{figure}

\blindtext[50]


\section{Second section}\label{secondsec}




\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost works... but it fails (compiler fails and stop) when there's a `\ref` command inside a `\caption{}` :-( . I get the same failure with other tricks.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi: Try `\protect\ref` inside of a caption

Comment: Woooooooow! This fixes my problem and my script now works fine! Thank you!

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi: I'll add a fix such that you don't need to specify `\protect\ref` all the time any longer

Comment: That would be even better! But I get: `! Undefined control sequence.
\@begindocumenthook ...herefusage }}}} \robustify`

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi: Have you added `\usepackage{etoolbox}`?

Comment: Oh sorry. I missed it! That's great! Thank you very very much!